# Is there any inbuilt Mathematica function that can be used as a steerable filter?

Tags: image-processing

I need a  [steerable pyramid filter](http://people.csail.mit.edu/billf/www/papers/steerpaper91FreemanAdelson.pdf) for images and volumes. Is there any built-in *Mathematica* function or package for that as there is in [Matlab](https://github.com/LabForComputationalVision/matlabPyrTools)?

**Edit 1:** Firstly, I didn't ask for an implementation of a steerable filter. My query was mainly to know whether there **exists** any such built-in function in *Mathematica*. [This](http://bmia.bmt.tue.nl/Education/Courses/FEV/book/pdf/19%20Steerable%20kernels.pdf) provoked me to guess that there might exist such an implementation already. Specifically if one looks at *page 342, Task 19.7*.

An example code for the steerable filter (in older version) can be found in *Section 19.5*.

Firstly, current *Mathematica* version does not have any built-in function of the form `gD[a_,b_,c_,d_]` which is required to run the functions

```
gDϕ[im_, nv_, nw_, σ_, ϕ_ ]
gDϕN[im_, nv_, nw_, σ_, ϕ_]
```

and finally to get the result as in `Figure 19.6`.

**Edit 2:**

Here is the [link](http://www.mathvisiontools.net/) for the complete source code and the pdf files as well. The only problem is that the Mathematica code is for version 4.2 and I need to find out the way to use it in Mathematica 11.2 specifically for chapter 19.

Comment: @rhermans Question updated.

Comment: @rhermans I have got the function `gD`.

Comment: Currently, I would say the question is clear with informative links, but finding out the actual code that has to be changed from version 4.2 to 11.3 is somewhat hard.

Comment: @AntonAntonov you are right. I have tried with the code provided in the book, however, I could not resolve some unidentified terms. Therefore, I have asked Prof. Bart M. ter Haar Romeny for an updated version of the code specifically for the steerable filters, if he has any updated implementation.

Comment: Well I looked into that notebook. The code is not that hard to update to 11.3. There are minor changes like replacing the custom made function `DisplayTogether` and the obsolete one `GraphicsArray` with `GraphicsGrid`. I did take from the web my GIF image to use as "fabric.gif". The problem is the missing definition of `gD`, which I assume is defined in some of the other notebooks on that site.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Yes, I have got the function `gD` as I have mentioned in one of my earlier comments. However, there still remains some unknown terms such as `kernelSampleRange` in `gd`,` L[x,y]` in `gD\[Phi]`, `L[x,y]`, `im0`, `n`, `m` in `gD\[Phi]N`.